# Java recursive Method with different calls - Values of variables hard to follow

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I try to understand this recursive method, but I get confused.

The output is:
x:3 
x:4 
x:3
y:4

I've come to understand it this far: At first x:3 is printed, because we passed the numbers 3 and 4. Then it calls the method again now with x-1, y. But the positions are swapped. Please explain what the values of x and y are at the different points after the second method call and how they change after each call. Thanks.

```
   public class Test {

      public static void obscure (int x, int y){

         if (x * y <= 4){
            return;
         }
         System.out.println("x: " + x); // X ist 4

         if (x >= y){ 
            obscure(x-1, y);
         }else{
            obscure(y,x-1);
            System.out.println("y: " + y);
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args){
    obscure(3,4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: `But the positions are swapped` That's correct. `if (x >= y){ ` -  `x` here is `3`, `y` is `4`. It goes to the `else` block, passing `y` as first parameter and `x-1` as second parameter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in this code:

```
first call: obscure(3,4) //x=3,y=4
   output: x:3
   else clause (not x(3) >= y(4)) 
       second call: obscure (4,2) //x=4,y=2
           output: x:4
           if clause ( x(4) >= y(2)
               third call: obscure(3,2) //x=3,y=2
                   output: x:3
                   if clause ( x(3) >= y(2))
                       fourth call: obscure(2,2) //x=2, y=2
                           x(2)*y(2) <= 4 //returns
                       end of fourth call
                end of third call
       end of second call
       output in else clause of first call: y:4
end of first call
```